# Transformation theorem for triple integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $U = [0, 1] \times [1, 2] \times [0, 1]$, and $V = G(U)$. Find $V$, and write the  triple integral
>   $$     \exp(-x_3^2)\sin(x_1x_2) \,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3$$
>   as an integral in terms of the variables $(u_1, u_2, u_3)$. Do not evaluate.

I think we need to find the equations of the boundarys first, then we can compute the inverse and the det and just plug things in. However, I don't know how to get the equations of the boundary.

Comment: What is $G$ here? Also, see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). (Or look at how I formatted the formulas in your question.)

Comment: G is a function of U. It doesn't specify anything else

Comment: V is the boundary of the triple integral

Comment: So, how are you going to compute the inverse and determinant of unspecified letter $G$?

Comment: Im stuck here as well. I don't know how to start it.  Usually u would make a substitution first but i dont know the equations of the boundary

Comment: The boundary of $U$ has simple equations: $x_1=0$, $x_1=1$, $x_2=1$, $x_2=2$, ... you get the idea. You just don't have anything to plug these into.

Comment: This question needs more information. As it is it does not make sense.